# UserForm Combobox Filtering

Tags: excel, vba

I have got this combobox with many values (in my case numbers) in a USERFORM.
I'd like it to behave like a filtering so you can jump to an item in the combobox simply by typing only the first few numbers of the string.

Is there any way to have this done in a simple ways?

Answer (score 0):

The feature you are after is commonly referred to as "autocomplete". There are many examples you can find if you use this term. Here is one example: [Autocomplete Combo](http://www.contextures.com/exceluserformcomboboxes.html). At the bottom of the page you could download a working example.

In particular see the MatchEntry Property of the combo box as below:
[image].

Formal description is in [MSDN-MatchEntry Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278672.aspx).

Comment: i'm already aware of that feature inside a worksheet, and i had already find solution for this combobox filtering inside worksheet.
but the problem is i want the filtering feature inside a userform, because i create the combobox in a userform.

Comment: thanks for this i'm gonna exercise with that property while waiting for better solution